# Remove data from class object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two class which is Animal and Zoo. Animal for store the data of the type and its sex

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, types, sex):
        self.types=types
        self.sex = sex
```

Zoo class is for storing all objects from the Animal class.

```
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.zoo =[]
    def enters (animal):
        self.zoo.append(animal)
    def removes (self, types, sex):
        self.types = types
        self.sex=sex     
        for i in range(0,len(self.zoo)):
            if self.name.lower() and self.sex.lower() in self.zoo[i]:
                del self.zoo[i]
                break
            else:
                print("The animal is not exist")
                break
```

I want to do the removal of the animal using their type and sex.

```
p=Zoo()
dog = Animal("Poodle","male")
cat = Animal("Persian","female")
p.enters(dog)
p.enters(cat)

p.removes("Poodle","male")
```

I got an error that said the object Animal is not iterable.
Did anyone know what I have been missing? I thought I already store zoo in the list.

Comment: self.zoo store the objects as Animal class object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```py
if self.name.lower() and self.sex.lower() in self.zoo[i]:
```

Firstly, the conition will always be `True` (because `self.name.lower()` will always return a non-empty string except if `self.name` is empty, and non-empty strings evaluate to True). Next, you are trying to iterate over your `Animal` class (`x in y` iterates over y and checks if any of the elements of y == x). That's why you get that not iterable error. Finally, `self.name` is nowhere defined, so I wonder how you get to that error at all. Code should be like this:

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex

class Zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.zoo =[]

    def add_animal(animal):
        self.zoo.append(animal)
    
    def remove_animal(self, name, sex):   
        for n, animal in enumerate(self.zoo): # produces a list like [(0, Animal("Poodle","male")), (1, Animal("Penguin","male"))]
            if name == animal.name and sex == animal.sex:
                del self.zoo[i]
                break
        else: # This gets only excuted when the break above was NOT executed
            print("Animal %s with sex %s does not exist" % (name, sex))

p = Zoo()
dog = Animal("Poodle", "male")
cat = Animal("Persian", "female")
p.add_animal(dog)
p.add_animal(cat)

p.remove_animal("Poodle","male")
```

Comment: When I run your code, it shows an error at the line ```del self.zoo[i]``` I wonder what it is and it should be changed with ```del self.zoo[n]``` and it works like magic. enumerate solve the problem

Comment: @Trojan666 sorry about that, I meant to change `zoo[i]` to `zoo[n]`, just forgot to do it XD. Glad it works, Please accept my answer using the grey checkmark on the left of it. That will give me 15+ reputation points and you 2+. And optioanlly vote it up, which will give me 10 reputation